Booting a raspberry pi disk image using qemu without an external kernel?
Back in the day, qemu didn't have actual support for the raspberry pi, so while it was possible to boot a raspberry pi disk image in a virtual environment, it required a special kernel. Since then, qemu has developed support for several pi models; the latest release purports to include support for everthing from the 0 through the 4b.
Despite this new support, it appears to still be necessary to extract the kernel from the image in order to boot it. That is, this works (after extracting the necessary kernel and dtb to local files):
qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -M raspi3b \
  -m 1g \
  -kernel boot/vmlinuz-6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 \
  -append 'console=tty0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1' \
  -dtb boot/firmware/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb \
  -drive file=rpidisk.qcow2,if=sd

But this doesn't:
qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -M raspi3b \
  -m 1g \
  -drive file=rpidisk.qcow2,if=sd

Why isn't qemu able to boot the kernel embedded in the image?
